# Objective-C: Custom setter warnings for property type conversion

Tags: ios, objective-c, setter

I'm writing a client that hits an API.  The API spits out this:

```
Id: 33,
UserUrl: "https://example.com/username/profile",
Title: "I wanna give 'em the holy boot!",
IsOnline: "no"
```

I consume the JSON as a NSDictionary and convert it to my User object using setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:.  My User.m has custom setters to take the incoming UserUrl string and bend it into a NSURL like so:

```
- (void)setUserUrl:(NSString *)stringInput  {
    _UserUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:stringInput];
}
```

This works fine.  When I try the same with the BOOLs, I get a warning:

**Conflicting parameter types in implementation of 'setIsSecret:': 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') vs 'NSString *__strong'**

```
    - (void)setIsOnline:(NSString *)stringInput {
        if ([stringInput isEqualToString:@"yes"])
            _IsOnline = YES;
        else
            _IsOnline = NO;
    }
```

User.h

```
@interface Achievement : NSObject

    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSNumber *Id;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *UserUrl;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *Title;
    @property (nonatomic) BOOL IsOnline;

@end
```

My code compiles and runs fine, I'd just like to know why it warns me on the BOOL property but not the NSString property.  This is for an API wrapper, so I'd prefer not to surpress the warnings.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** rmaddy had the correct answer. For anyone looking to do the same thing in the future, create a custom initializer to do all your type conversions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the `IsOnline` property to have a type of `BOOL` but your `setIsOnline:` method takes an `NSString *` parameter. It needs to be a `BOOL` parameter.

Remember, the `IsOnline` property results in the synthesize methods:

```
- (BOOL)IsOnline;

- (void)setIsOnline:(BOOL)value;
```

Unlike other languages, Objective-C doesn't support method overloading. The data type of the parameter is not part of the method name. Your:

```
- (void)setIsOnline:(NSString *)value
```

method conflicts with the expect one.

You should be getting the same error for your `setUserUrl:` method too since the property type is `NSURL *` but your method takes an `NSString *`. I'm not sure why you don't have an issue with that one.

If you want a separate method for setting a property given a different type then you should have a method name that is different than the standard property setter method name.

Side note - it is standard practice that variable, property, and method names begin with lowercase letters, not uppercase. Only classes should start with uppercase letters.

Comment: I thought I could overload the setters (well, I guess I technically *can* since the code runs just fine).  I'm really curious now why the NSString/NSURL properties aren't giving me the same warnings.  I found out the warnings only happen when trying to convert from and object to a primitive, not converting between objects.  Anyways, this was helpful. And thanks for the style note.

Comment: I think I can guess that your NSString/NSURL property "sort of" works because they are both objects. But I bet if you actually assign an `NSURL` value to the property, your setter will be called and your code will crash because you will end up passing an `NSURL` object to the `URLWithString:` method. Try it.

Comment: Yep, crashes with 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. I made this a lot cleaner by adding a customer initializer.